# How to enter recovery mode in BlueStacks?

Tags: recovery-mode, custom-roms, clockworkmod-recovery, bluestacks

I have downloaded and installed BlueStacks rooted version with ClockworkMod Recovery installed through Rom Manager. Now I want to install a custom ROM, and I need to enter the recovery mode.

How to access recovery mode in BlueStacks?

Comment: I will be blunt: you can't. Unless you use a special bluestacks (there's one floating somewhere.)

Comment: Emulators usually don't have that. Want something new? Try VMWare + Android-x86, or Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot enter recovery mode with BlueStacks.

The recovery needs a partition for the recovery as mb, but I think BlueStacks remove that partition. So when you reboot into the recovery, it will be blank.

You can only install Xposed for modding BlueStacks, like display, setting, etc.